# threadblocks and stream multiprocessors in C

Tags: cuda

I was told that in order to have a fully efficient CUDA C program, the number of threadblocks should be at least 3 or 4 times the number of stream multiprocessors.

My questions is: is the statement true? If yes/no why? what should the ratio ideally be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to have multiple threadblocks that can be launched on each SM, when a kernel launches.

The GPU is a latency-hiding machine.  In order to hide latency, it needs as much potential work as possible.  Potential work can be translated into "warps that are ready to execute".  This scenario can be maximized by having more than one threadblock per SM.

At some point, the GPU (SMs) run out of resources to host additional threadblocks.  This running-out point might occur at around 3-4 threadblocks per SM, depending on the specifics of resource usage (registers, threads, shared memory, etc.) of the threadblocks, and the GPU type.  Therefore, launching more than the amount that can be actually scheduled on the SMs won't help with concurrency, latency-hiding, occupancy, or other figures of merit for a parallel program.  Those threadblocks will just wait until scheduling slots open up on the SMs.

There is no fixed ratio, but an analysis of typical threadblocks with 256 or 512 threads per block suggest that you will want at least 3-8 threadblocks per SM, to maximize occupancy (this varies based on GPU architecture as well).  With 1024 threads per block, it might only require 2 threadblocks per SM.

GPU programs typically don't dramatically slow down if work is partitioned into more threadblocks, so the numbers are not a hard-and-fast rule, and the actual behavior will depend on other factors like shared memory usage (if any).  It's just a general guideline.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! so let me see if i got it right: a good idea would be for example to fix the number of threadblocks to 4*SM (if I have 12 SM i could set threadblocks = 48) and the increase the number of threads per block until i found the optimum; does it make sense? Another thing: how can i know if i reached the maximum occupancy?

Comment: You can measure occupancy with any of the profiling tools.

Comment: Do you have perhaps a reference where it states that the GPU may run out of resources at around 3/4 threadblocks per SM? unfortunately I couldn't find any info about it in the internet... thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It's in the programming guide.  Look at the GPU specifications.  If the SM can have up to 2048 threads resident, then it can support 4 threadblocks of 512 threads each.  The calculations would be similar if you used shared memory or registers as a limiting resource.